# Comparing exact data structure

Tags: php, arrays, database, if-statement, structure

How to actually compare two different structure of data from the database?
Or I should ask, how to check whether the structure is matching exactly to another or not.

For example:

I would like to compare the structure by simple data with another data with array.

```
if($data == $data[1])   << this case will have to return false because first data do not have array.
```

2nd sample if the data is :

```
if($data[1] == $data[1][2][3])  << this case should also return false.
```

BUT

```
if($data[5][6] == $data[1][2])  << this case must return a true as I only wanted to compare the structure..
```

any php professional knows how to solve it flexiblely?

Comment: And your structure is..? Any professional will say: you can not compare anything with undefined data structure.

Comment: So you want to check data/values or database/table structure?

Comment: no specific structure but to compare both data whether they are having the same type of structure.

Comment: I still don't see any sense in your question's samples (since `$data[5][6]` could be, for example, an object, while `$data[1][2]` - boolean)

Comment: erm.. I mean to compare if a data carries how many array or does it carries any array or not. if first data carries 1 array, but second data carries 2 arrays. that means their structure was not match.